# Windows Azure , blob not loaded to LocalResource

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying implement Using local storage with BLOB storage .
I went through http://allcomputers.us/windows_azure/using-local-storage-with-blob-storage-(part-1)---using-a-local-cache---defining-and-accessing-local-storage.aspx
and re factored my GetBlob method as below .

```
public Stream GetBlob(string blobAddress, string CONTAINER_NAME)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = null;
        stream = CheckInLocalCache(blobAddress);
        if (stream==null)
        {
            CloudBlobContainer container = Client.GetContainerReference(CONTAINER_NAME);
            if (container != null)
            {
                stream = new MemoryStream();
                container.GetBlobReference(blobAddress).DownloadToStream(stream);
            }
        }

        return stream;
    }

    private static MemoryStream CheckInLocalCache(string blobAddress)
    {
        MemoryStream localBlobStream=null;
        LocalResource localBlobCache = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("localBlobCache");
        if (localBlobCache != null)
        {
            string localCacheRootDirectory = localBlobCache.RootPath;
            string blobName = blobAddress.Split('/')[blobAddress.Split('/').Length - 1];
            if (File.Exists(localBlobCache.RootPath + blobName))
            {
                localBlobStream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(localBlobCache.RootPath + blobName));
            }               
        }
        return localBlobStream;
    }
```

In Config  file i added this

```
<WebRole name="ServiceRuntimeWebsite">
   <LocalResources>
      <LocalStorage name="localBlobCache"
                    cleanOnRoleRecycle="true"
                    sizeInMB="100" />
   </LocalResources>
</WebRole>
```

When i run my prject in development environment , i see the folder "localBlobCache" is created . But even after many times loading blobs from azure it never really loaded to my local storage . Can anyone tell Whats wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like anything in the code you shared saves the file to the cache directory. You probably want something in GetBlob that saves the blob to a file if it isn't already there.

Comment: I should write  code for that or wat ? . Isn't that automatically handled by azure ? .   If i am explicitly writing the code to save in  cache directory . What is the necessity of storing it in a cache and retrieving through localBlobCache.RootPath . I can take any other directory and write a custom code for that right ?

Comment: There's nothing built in to Windows Azure (or the storage client library) that saves things to the local disk, so yes, you'd have to build that yourself. The reason to use a declared LocalStorage resource is because this gives you guaranteed disk space on the VM. If you just write to a random directory on the C: drive, you may or may not find you have enough space.